# bash - rename fasta headers and filenames within subdirectories - append prefix

Tags: bash, recursion, sed, rename, bioinformatics

A simplified example of my file structure is this:

```
/Assemblies/A_velvet/contigs.fasta
/Assemblies/A_velvet/info.log
/Assemblies/BB_velvet/contigs.fasta
/Assemblies/BB_velvet/info.log
```

I am trying to write a script that I can pass the Assemblies directory - then it will:

1. loop through each subdirectory (A_velvet, BB_velvet) - take the strain name (A, BB) add it as a prefix to all files within (ie. A_contigs.fasta, A_file.log).
2. Add the same prefix to the fasta headers within the contigs.fasta file.
   Maybe use sed command to substitute ('s/>NODE/>${name}/g')?

I've found alot of very closely related questions, but can't seem to make them work. Any help is very much appreciated! Here's my code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Run with: ./test.sh <assembly_directory>
#dir= directory with all assemblies inside it
dir=$1
for subdir in $dir 
do
    if [ -d "${subdir}" ]; then
    name=`basename $subdir|cut -d '_' -f 1`;
    echo "${subdir} name ${name}"
         for * in $subdir;
        `do mv "$file" "$subdir/${name}_$(basename "$file")"; done
    fi
done
```

Comment: What output are you getting?   How do you know it's not working?

Comment: @DaleWilson - Output is just an error,  line 5: `*': not a valid identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method for looping through the contents of a directory isn't going to work. In the first case, the only item in your loop is $dir. I'm not sure what you're trying to do in the second case. Try something like this:

```
dir=$1 
for subdir in `ls $dir` 
do
    if [ -d "${subdir}" ]; then
        name=`basename $subdir|cut -d '_' -f 1`;
        echo "${subdir} name ${name}"
        for file in `ls $subdir`;
        do mv "$file" "$subdir/${name}_$(basename "$file")"; done
    fi
done
```

Comment: thanks for taking a look at my question @heathobrien. When I tried your modified code, nothing happened. Good in that the error was gone, but bad in that that no files within the subdirectories were renamed. So tried a couple modifications and still can't seem to get it. I took out the if statments (lines 4 and 9) - then it gives the following warning messages: _Assemblies/A_velvet/: name :
ls: cannot access Assemblies/A_velvet/:: No such file or directory_
 _contigs.fasta name contigs.fasta
ls: cannot access contigs.fasta: No such file or directory_

Comment: The output I'm looking to achieve is: `Assemblies/A_velvet/A_contigs.fasta`

Comment: try putting $dir/ in front of $subdir wherever it occurs. You'll also need to change the last line to something like: mv $dir/$subdir/$file $dir/$subdir/${name}_$file